# Laravel controller method with model as parameter

Tags: laravel, model, controller, url-routing, laravel-5.7

I created an model using `php artisan make:model Transaction -a`, so it generated a migration, factory, and resource controller for the model too. Everything working as expected, but I realized this in controller code:

```
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\Transaction  $transaction
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(Transaction $transaction)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\Transaction  $transaction
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit(Transaction $transaction)
{
    //
}
```

Looks like it's expecting an model instance in `show()` and `edit()` methods, what seems to be a helper to return the view, but how can I integrate this in web routing?

---

*English isn't my native language.*

Comment: just pass *id* of the object in your urls, then laravel will do the magic for you and you will have the object in your methods

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din thanks! in older versions I should fetch the model instance with Eloquent, this change confused me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your route is `administração/transações/{transaçõe}` and your model is *Transaction* then laravel doesn't know what to do with it!

so to make it work, there are two ways:

- you have to bind it explicity according to this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#explicit-binding):

  add `Route::model('transaçõe', App\Transaction::class);` to `boot()` method of your *RouteServiceProvider* as follows:

  ```
  public function boot()
  {
      parent::boot();

      Route::model('transaçõe', App\Transaction::class);
  }
  ```
- **OR** you change the route to `administração/transações/{transaction}`.

Answer (score 0):

Run `php artisan route:list` on console. You will get all routes of your appilcation. This is list of `Route::resource('admin/blog-category', 'BlogCategoryController');` routes.By route list you will get idea of URI and Action.

```
|        | POST      | api/admin/blog-category                      | blog-category.store   | App\Http\Controllers\BlogCategoryController@store                      | api          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/admin/blog-category                      | blog-category.index   | App\Http\Controllers\BlogCategoryController@index                      | api          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/admin/blog-category/create               | blog-category.create  | App\Http\Controllers\BlogCategoryController@create                     | api          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/admin/blog-category/{blog_category}      | blog-category.show    | App\Http\Controllers\BlogCategoryController@show                       | api          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | api/admin/blog-category/{blog_category}      | blog-category.update  | App\Http\Controllers\BlogCategoryController@update                     | api          |
|        | DELETE    | api/admin/blog-category/{blog_category}      | blog-category.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\BlogCategoryController@destroy                    | api          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/admin/blog-category/{blog_category}/edit | blog-category.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\BlogCategoryController@edit                       | api          |
```

check `BlogCategoryController@show` Uri you will get `api/admin/blog-category/{blog_category}`. that is you have to pass one parameter.As parameter you have to pass blog categiry id.

Ex: if url is `api/admin/blog-category/10`

```
public function show(Blog $BlogCategory)
    {
        $blogCategory = $BlogCategory;
    }
```

In `$blogCategory` you will get result of blog category which id is 10.

Comment: for some reason it's not working. I wrote the `show()` method like this: `return view('administração.transações.show')->with('transação', $transaction);` and the route is `URI: administração/transações/{transaçõe}; Name: transações.show; Action: App\Http\Controllers\TransactionController@show`, but when I try to fetch it using administração/transações/{id} it returns an 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

The 404 error I mentioned probably is a bug on routes with utf-8. When I change to trasacoes (from 'transações'), it works. I'll file an issue.